# Want to update the progress bar from activity for each item on uploading item and adding it to recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a chat app in which I want to upload files with progress showing but could not able to update UI as upload progress.

I created an interface `ProgressUpdateListener` in the class `MultipartUtility` used to upload file and creating a object of `MultipartUtility` and progress listener in which I call `PublishProgress` to update progress for `AsyncTask`.

Created one interface in Activity and used to update progress in adapter

```
/* to get progress update from MultiUtility class using interface in actviity */
MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(strings[0], charset, new MultipartUtility.ProgressUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(final long progress, final String msg_id) {
        //Toast.makeText(ChatRoom.this, progress+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("DataP", progress + "");
        publishProgress(String.valueOf(progress), msg_id);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mOnDataChangeListener.onDataChanged(progress, msg_id);//activity interface function
                dataBaseHelper.updateProgress(msg_id, (int) progress);
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
});

/* to get update in adapter from activity using interface function of activity */
activity.setOnDataChangeListener(new ChatRoom.OnDataChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(long progress, String msg_id) {
        try {
            Log.e("ProgressInAdapter", progress + " ****** " + msg_id);
            if (object.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(msg_id)) {
                object.setProgress((int) (progress * 10));

                dataSet.set(listPosition, object);

                ((MyVideoHolder)holder).pbProgress.setProgress(object.getProgress());
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store Viewholder position and progress on change, use this position while update progress bar.
 If  `ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition() == position` => Then we are at right viewholder, update UI, otherwise do nothing

You have to initialize listener inside `onBindViewHolder` and pass to Asynctask to update correct ViewHolder

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

// listener passed to asynctask to call on progress change
        viewHolder.update( new OnProgressUpdate() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(DownloadUpdate update1,String msg1) {
//  check whether listener called for right position of item list
                    if(update1.getPosition() == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION || 
                    update1.getPosition()!= viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()) return;

                    viewHolder.bar.setProgress(update1.getProgress());
                    viewHolder.bar.setMax(update1.getMaxProgress());
                    viewHolder.msg.setText(msg1);
                }
            };);


    }
```

You have to maintain state outside list because ViewHolder are re-used, order of viewholder is not sure to store state.

I have implemented and tested with custom class to store progress and  implementation [here](https://github.com/ankitsharma5652/Android-Progress-List)